# How to convert today date local date to UTC with time 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 in javascript or Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timestamp, momentjs

I am sending Start Date and End Date as parameters after converting those dates into UTC. I am facing difficulty due to time span.
I have used the moment.js to convert into UTC format.

```
var today = new Date();
var todayDate = moment.utc(today).format();
       
var yestardayObj = moment().subtract(1, 'days');
var yestardayDate = moment.utc(yestardayObj).format();

$scope.toDate = todayDate;
$scope.fromDate = yestardayDate;



 For example:
    StartDate: 2023-02-19T09:34:44Z
    EndDate: 2023-02-20T09:34:44Z
```

I need to get the data for yestarday date but it won't work

For that I need datetime format like,

```
StartDate: 2023-02-19T00:00:00Z
EndDate: 2023-02-20T23:59:59Z
```

Please help me to derive above datetime format.

Comment: The question is unclear. Why do you use the current timestamp if you want 00:00:00 and 23:59:59? 11:59:59 is not 23:59:59. Do you know the `set...` methods: [`setMinutes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes), [`setSeconds`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setSeconds), [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), ...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for get start and end date.

```
var today = moment.utc().startOf('day');
var yesterday = moment.utc().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day');

var start = yesterday.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss') + 'Z';
var end = today.format('YYYY-MM-DDT23:59:59') + 'Z';

console.log(start);
console.log(end);
```

Output:

```
"2023-02-19T00:00:00Z"
"2023-02-20T23:59:59Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you mean, however if you want the start of the current UTC day and the start of the previous UTC day, it's very easy in pain JS.

To get the start of today's UTC date, create a *Date* and set it's UTC time to 0hrs. The start of the previous day is 24 hours earlier, or subtract 1 from the date.

```js
let startTodayUTC = new Date();
startTodayUTC.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);

// Because ECMAScript UTC days are always exactly 8.64e7ms long
let startYesterdayUTC = new Date(startTodayUTC - 8.64e7);

// Alternative 1
let startYesterdayUTC1 = new Date(startTodayUTC);
startYesterdayUTC1.setUTCDate(startYesterdayUTC1.getUTCDate() - 1);

// Alternative 2
let startYesterdayUTC2 = new Date();
startYesterdayUTC2.setUTCHours(-24,0,0,0);

console.log(`startTodayUTC     : ${startTodayUTC.toISOString()}\n` +
            `startYesterdayUTC : ${startYesterdayUTC.toISOString()}\n` +
            `startYesterdayUTC1: ${startYesterdayUTC1.toISOString()}\n` +
            `startYesterdayUTC2: ${startYesterdayUTC2.toISOString()}`);
```

If you want the start of the current and previous local day but expressed as UTC in ISO 8601 format, it's not much more difficult:

```js
let startToday = new Date();
startToday.setHours(0,0,0,0);

let startYesterday = new Date(startToday);
startYesterday.setDate(startYesterday.getDate() - 1);

console.log(`startToday    :   ${startToday.toISOString()}\n` +
            `startYesterday:   ${startYesterday.toISOString()}`);
```

Using *setDate* to set the date to yesterday avoids potential daylight saving issues with local dates.